# How does url http://app.mywebsite.com works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, routes, dns, cloud

I am currently developping a SASS web application, and I want to deploy my react app under an url like "https://app.my-website.example". So I tried to buy the domain name "app.my-website.example", but apparently, domain name cannot contain "." character.

**How can I deploy it under an url like "https://app.my-website.example" ?**

I have seen quantity of modern websites with url containing "app." at the beginning.
For example, website about crypto usually have a traditional static website describing the project, deployed on an url like "https://website.example". And then, their actual application, which does stuff, is deployed on an url like "https://app.website.example".

This is also true for most web application out there.

I use **AWS Amazon cloud** if it helps you answer me.

Btw, I have already bought the domain name like "my-website.example" and have deployed my static website on it.

Comment: "So I tried to buy the domain name "app.my-website.example"" (changed your hostname to remove your bad obfuscation). Domain name registration does not work like this. You will need to buy `my-website.example` through any registrar accredited to sell `.example` domain names. After which you need to choose a DNS provider (can be often your registrar too but does not need to be your registrar either) and then you can edit the zone through some GUI or API, to map `app` in your domain to whatever server you need, through A/AAAA/CNAME records.

Comment: Your registrar and/or DNS provider should be your 2 first point of contacts for questions like this. Because, at its current stage, your question is kind of offtopic here as not related to programming but more server/DNS configuration.

Comment: I don't see why a question about DNS, network and cloud should not be asked in stack overflow.

Comment: If you have a better place to ask, let me know.

For me, your downvote are not justified. Currently, I think my question and the tags I used are legit.

I should have clarified that indeed, I am mainly a developper. So I am not familiar with how DNS works and how Registar interract with DNS provider. But I said that I am using AWS platform. Obviously, I meant I am using AWS Registar and their DNS provider.

I posted the answer I needed below.

Comment: By the way, ".example" was not "bad offuscation". It was just a quick example. As I do not care if a registrar selling this extension exists. I think there are not a lot of people today who directly communicate with their registrar. Indeed, services, like AWS, allow you to buy any domain names with existing extension without having to contact 2 separated entities when buying "mywebsite.com" and "mywebsite.de". Plus, ".example" is an existing extension. Anyway, thank you for you benevolence and for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: " I don't see why a question about DNS, network and cloud should not be asked in stack overflow. " Because StackOverflow is about **programming** question. See the help and the tour sections.

Comment: "By the way, ".example" was not "bad offuscation".".  `.example` is fine indeed, but not what you used. You use a real domain name in `.com`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

So the answer to my question is that I need to create a sub domain inside my main domain.
I don't need to buy anything else to create the subdomain, since I already own the domain. It is the main advantage compared to buying "app-mywebsite.com". Plus, it will be easier for google to reference my app.

On amazon, you need to go to the "route 53" service to create the subdomain and then redirect it to you application. The doc to do that is here :
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53